# File Explorer icon size for View > Medium icons and View > Small icons

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Using Windows 10. I have a couple of folders on the desktop which contain shortcuts which I use regularly, but I can't get the icons to look good.

In Windows Explorer, the `View > Small icons` gives 16x16 icons which are too small. The `View > Medium icons` option, however, gives 64x64 icons which are **way** too big and quite ugly and pixellated.

Ideally, the `View > Medium icons` option would use 32x32 icons. Is it possible to configure this?

Comment: Did you try altering Scale? Start, Settings, System.

Comment: No, didn't know about that setting. Where is it exactly? I wouldn't want to change settings everywhere in Windows, BTW, just the size of icons for `View > xxx icons` .

Comment: Set icons to normal (small) and try a larger scale. That helps icons and text.
Look in System and Scale is there (100% and change to 125%)

Comment: Medium gives 48x48 but otherwise I join the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the values are hardcoded so it's impossible to do so.

Alternatively, you can use Ctrl+Scroll to get precise zoom (back in Win 7 we had this in form of slider but now I believe it's gone as I can't find any) and go to Folder Options and Click [Apply to Folders](https://mywindowshub.com/how-to-apply-a-folders-view-to-all-folders-of-same-template-type-in-windows-10/) to make the view permanent/default.